# how do I control multiple google streetviewpanorma maps with setPOV and google.maps.event.addListener

Tags: google-street-view

I want to control the POV (heading and pitch ) of multiple street view panoramas so when one panorama is interactively moved up down left right the other panorama moves with it

I can get this to work where interaction with panorama moves panorama2 another using this javascript:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'pov_changed', function() {
panorama2.setPov({ heading: panorama.getPov().heading + $headingoffset, pitch: panorama.getPov().pitch, zoom: panorama.getPov().zoom });
});
```

when I add the same code to control panorama via interaction with panorma2 both panoramas fail to be interactive so I assume the code causes a loop

```
google.maps.event.addListener(panorama2, 'pov_changed', function() {
panorama.setPov({ heading: panorama2.getPov().heading - $headingoffset, pitch: panorama2.getPov().pitch, zoom: panorama2.getPov().zoom });
});
\\The $headingoffset value is the degree of difference between to two panoramas
```

do I have to turn the listener off and on again for the other panorama while I change the POV - if so how

Or can this be done via a DIV mouse event instead